# Как сделать отправку файла через ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, html5

**Как через ajax отправить на сервер url файла для дальнейшей обработки??**
Кто понимает о чем я помогите, 3тие сутки ни могу сделать... знатоки и специалисты жду ваших предложений, большое спасибо

```js
function Send(id) {

  var name = document.getElementById('name-' + id).value,
    email = document.getElementById('email-' + id).value,
    work = document.getElementById('work-' + id).value,
    file = document.getElementById('file-' + id).files[0];

  var type = file['type'],
    txt = 'text/plain',
    pdf = 'application/pdf',
    doc = 'application/msword',
    docx = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document';



  if (name == undefined || email == undefined || file == undefined) {
    //Ошибка! Не все поля заполнены
    $('#pushmsg-' + id).addClass('alert-danger').append('Заполните все поля').show(300).delay(3000).fadeOut(300);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#pushmsg-' + id).removeClass('alert-danger').empty();
    }, 3800);
  } else {

    if (type == txt || type == pdf || type == doc || type == docx) {




      alert('ajax send');

    } else {
      //Ошибка! Формат файла недопустим!
      $('#pushmsg-' + id).removeClass('alert-danger').empty();
      $('#pushmsg-' + id).addClass('alert-warning').append('Формат файла недопустим!').show(300).delay(3000).fadeOut(300);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#pushmsg-' + id).removeClass('alert-warning').empty();
      }, 3800);
    }

  }



}
```

```html
<form method="post" class="<?=$ElementData['ID']?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           
        <div class="form-group">
         <label>Имя Фамилия Отчество<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
         <input id="name-<?=$ElementData['ID']?>" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ф.и.о">
        </div>
           
        <div class="form-group">
         <label>Email<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
         <input id="email-<?=$ElementData['ID']?>" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email">
        </div>
           
        <div class="form-group">
         <label>Прикрепить файл<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
         <input id="file-<?=$ElementData['ID']?>" type="file" accept="<?=$type?>" class="form-control">
        </div>
           
        <input id="work-<?=$ElementData['ID']?>" type="hidden" value="<?=$ElementDataProp['NAME_JOB']['VALUE']?>" >
        <img style="display: none;" src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/images/cap/ajax.gif" alt="loader-<?=$ElementData['ID']?>" id='loader-<?=$ElementData['ID']?>'>
        <span class="btn btn-default" id="<?=$ElementData['ID']?>" onclick="Send(this. id)">Отправить</span>
           
       </form>






<?
echo 'ФИО: '.$_POST['name'].'<br>'.'Email: '.$_POST['email'].'<br>'.'Файл: '.$_FILES['file'].'<br>'.'Work: '.$_POST['work'].'<br>';

?>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Такой вариант вам подходит?

```
$.ajax( {
  url: 'скрипт для обработки',
  type: 'POST',
  data: new FormData('#id' или '.класс' формы),
  processData: false,
  contentType: false
} );
```

Comment: В коде выводится несколько форм, так вот как мне получить id текущей формы? как получить форму по id кнопки? id у формы и кнопки одинаков

Comment: id у формы необходимо заранее установить, и тогда вы сможете всегда иметь доступ к ней по этому id. например `<form id="main_form">`

Comment: id всегда денамический на орме как его получить?